# Prime number circle distribution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that Ulam spiral and the Klauber triangle and other shaped graph of the distribution of prime numbers, how about this circle distribution? Can we find more circles looks like this distribution?

$$
  \begin{matrix}
 \ 90 & \ 91 & 92 & \ 93 & 94 & \ 95 & \ 96 \\
 \ 99 & 100 & \color{red}{101} & 102 & \color{red}{103} & 104 & 105 \\
  108 & \color{red}{109} & 110 & 111 & 112 & \color{red}{113} & 114 \\
  117 & 118 & 119 & 120 & 121 & 122 & 123 \\
  126 & \color{red}{127} & 128 & 129 & 130 & \color{red}{131} & 132 \\
  135 & 136 & \color{red}{137} & 138 & \color{red}{139} & 140 & 141 \\
  144 & 145 & 146 & 147 & 148 & \color{blue}{149} & 150 \\
  \end{matrix}
$$

Edit: the example I give is not perfect, the perfect circle see paw88789's answer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?  You left off some numbers between $100$ and $141$, one of which is prime (namely $107$), .  Does that matter?  Can there be primes 'inside the circle'? Do you require those columns of non-primes bordering the 'circle' on the left and right?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFuR97YcSLM

Comment: Is this supposed to be a mod 7 sieve ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Does this video adress to this question ?

Comment: it relates to the other shapes of graphics @Peter

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee This isn't a sieve

Comment: Then it seems poorly explained. Because, if you cut out enough numbers and the primes behave as Polignac's conjecture suggest, you can form any shape by leaving numbers out.

Comment: Since we just need $\ 8\ $ primes with the same difference as the one shown in the picture, we probably can find infinite many such "prime circles". If no primes are allowed inside the circle this might make the task to find a tuple slightly more difficult.

Comment: @paw88789 I check 90-96 and 142-450 there's no primes, so  if require those columns and rows of non-primes bordering the 'circle' on the  top, right, bottom, and left is more intresting

Comment: @paw88789 Sure primes can't 'inside the circle', but can be out of the  border, such as $107$

Comment: The last row of your (edited) array appears to be wrong.  It should start at $144$ rather than $142$, but then you hit the prime $149$ in that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one that has a complete border and insides with non-primes. (All numbers in black are composite).

$$
  \begin{matrix}
 \ 2700 & \ 2701 & 2702 & \ 2703 & 2704 & \ 2705 & \ 2706 \\
 \ 3669 & 3670 & \color{red}{3671} & 3672 & \color{red}{3673} & 3674 & 3675 \\
  4638 & \color{red}{4639} & 4640 & 4641 & 4642 & \color{red}{4643} & 4644 \\
  5607 & 5608 & 5609 & 5610 & 5611 & 5612 & 5613 \\
  6576 & \color{red}{6577} & 6578 & 6579 & 6580 & \color{red}{6581} & 6582 \\
  7545 & 7546 & \color{red}{7547} & 7548 & \color{red}{7549} & 7550 & 7551 \\
  8514 & 8515 & 8516 & 8517 & 8518 & 8519 & 8520 \\
  \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Perfect circle.

Answer (score 1):

Slight bigger one:

$9 X 9$:
$$
  \begin{matrix}
  \ 98970 & \ 98971 & \ 98972 & \ 98973 & \ 98974 & \ 98975 & \ 98976 & \ 98977 & \ 98978 \\
  \ 99365 & \ 99366 & \ \color{red}{99367} & \ 99368 & \ 99369 & \ 99370 & \ \color{red}{99371} & \ 99372 & \ 99373 \\
  \ 99760 & \ \color{red}{99761} & \ 99762 & \ 99763 & \ 99764 & \ 99765 & \ 99766 & \ \color{red}{99767} & \ 99768 \\
  100155 & 100156 & 100157 & 100158 & 100159 & 100160 & 100161 & 100162 & 100163 \\
  100550 & 100551 & 100552 & 100553 & 100554 & 100555 & 100556 & 100557 & 100558 \\
  100945 & 100946 & 100947 & 100948 & 100949 & 100950 & 100951 & 100952 & 100953 \\
  101340 & \color{red}{101341} & 101342 & 101343 & 101344 & 101345 & 101346 & \color{red}{101347} & 101348 \\
  101735 & 101736 & \color{red}{101737} & 101738 & 101739 & 101740 & \color{red}{101741} & 101742 & 101743 \\
  102130 & 102131 & 102132 & 102133 & 102134 & 102135 & 102136 & 102137 & 102138 \\ 
  \end{matrix}
$$